# Как реализовать транскрипцию английских слов в Android приложении

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Пишу приложение для изучения английского, подскажите каким образом можно реализовать транскрипцию английских слов в приложении.

Первое что пришло в голову - хранить транскрипцию в БД (слово | транскрипция | перевод) и выводить ее пользователю соответственно из этой же БД. Но в транскрипции куча символов, которые могут не правильно отобразиться, а это не допустимо в приложении такого рода. И вообще если хранить транскрипцию в БД, то какую кодировку использовать?

Второе - это хранить в БД только слово и перевод, а транскрипцию выводить с помощью кода, который будет по определенным правилам конвертировать англ. слово в транскрипцию (т.е. набор букв и символов). В интернете есть сервисы которые из введенного слова формируют и выводят транскрипцию. Вот я и подумал может уже есть готовые скрипты или алгоритмы чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Может кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой? Подскажите пожалуйста какое решение лучшее и если возможно, способ реализации такого решения. Спасибо!

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что может существовать (верно работающий) алгоритм вывода транскрипции из написания слова. Там же море исключений из правил. Используйте unicode, там все нужные символы есть. См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 вполне складно хранит символы транскрипции. По моему скромному опыту могу сказать - сохраняйте в БД (слово | транскрипция | перевод). Или черпайте с сервера, но в любом случае транскрипцию легче уже иметь. Набраться её вдоволь можно [здесь](http://lingorado.com/transcription/)!